# Concatenating two multi dimensional arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have two Multidimensional arrays. I need to concatenate in either of the formats as shown bellow. Any ideas on how to do so?

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
B = np.array([[9,10],[11,12]])
C = np.concatenate(A,B)
```

Gives:

> Error : only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

```
# out required :
C = ([[1,2,3,4,9,10]
      ,[5,6,7,8,11,12]]

#or
C = ([[1,2,3,4][9,10]
       ,[5,6,7,8][11,12]] #nested array i[0][0] = [1,2,3,4] and i[0][1] = [9,10] ...
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: You're missing extra parentheses around `(A, B)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`numpy.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
>>> np.hstack((A, B))
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  9, 10],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8, 11, 12]])
```

This stacks arrays horizontally, like this (`A | B | C`):

```
a00, a01, b00, b01, c00, c01
a10, a11, b10, b11, c10, c11
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html), `np.concatenate` expects a sequence of arrays as first argument:

> numpy.concatenate((a1, a2, ...), axis=0, out=None)

Also you want to stack both arrays along the first axis, so:

```
np.concatenate((A, B), axis=1)

array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  9, 10],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8, 11, 12]])
```

---

You want to avoid having a nested array as in the second case, which is produced by the fact that you have a different amount of values along a same dimension. This implies loosing all vectorisation capabilities of NumPy.